# Падает приложение с ошибкой NullPointerException

Tags: android

Есть приложение онлайн радио. Класс `Player` это активити из которого запускается сервис. Иногда приложение падает, выбрасывая `NullPointerException` в сервисе на строчке `Player.btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);`. Почему-то `Player.btnPLayPause` в какой-то момент оказывается null. Подскажите как переделать код, чтобы не выбрасывало исключения?

Вот сам класс Player

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private String stream;
    private String radio;
    private String img;
    private int radioID;

    DBHeler db;

    private String MAYBE_ACTION = "MAYBE_ACTION";
    static boolean isPlay = false;
    static ImageButton btnPLayPause;
    private TextView txtRadio;
    private TextView txtTitle;
    private RoundedImageView imgRadio;

    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
    private String internetStatus = "";

    BroadcastReceiver br;
    private AsyncTask jsonTask;

    private ScheduledFuture<?> mScheduledFuture;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        db = new DBHeler(this);

        radioID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

        String query = "SELECT * " + " FROM " + Contract.Entry.TABLE_RADIO + " WHERE " + Contract.Entry._ID + " = " + radioID;
        Cursor cursor = db.database.rawQuery(query, null);
        try {
            if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {//Если кол-во записей в курсоре не равно нулю
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    //Получаем значения полей из таблицы
                    radio = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_TITLE));
                    stream = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_URL));
                    img = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IMAGE));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        /*Создаем баннер для AdMob*/
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        /*Создаем баннер для AdMob*/

        btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);
        txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadio);
        txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        imgRadio = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRadio);

        //Устанавливаем заголовок Activity
        setTitle(radio);
        txtRadio.setText(radio);

        try {
            InputStream ims = getAssets().open("img/" + img + ".png");
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
            imgRadio.setImageDrawable(d);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            return;
        }

        if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(this) != 0) {
            startPlayerService();
        }

        /*BroadcastReceiver*/
        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            // действия при получении сообщений
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                finish();
            }
        };
        // создаем фильтр для BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MAYBE_ACTION);
        // регистрируем (включаем) BroadcastReceiver
        registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);
        /*BroadcastReceiver*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mScheduledFuture = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                jsonTask = new ParseJSONTask().execute();
            }
        }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void startPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Player.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_STREAM, stream);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_RADIO, radio);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = true;
        btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
        mScheduledFuture = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                jsonTask = new ParseJSONTask().execute();
            }
        }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private void stopPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Player.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = false;
        btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
        txtTitle.setText("");
        mScheduledFuture.cancel(false);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver NetworkChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            internetStatus = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
            Toast.makeText(context, internetStatus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
        registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mScheduledFuture.cancel(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (NetworkChangeReceiver != null) unregisterReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }

    public void onPlayPause(View view) {
        if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(this) != 0 ) {
            if (isPlay) {
                stopPlayerService();
            } else {
                startPlayerService();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Нет подключения к интернету", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            stopPlayerService();
        }
    }

    private class ParseJSONTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://site.ru/info.json");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);

            JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
            String replaceStr = "(site.ru)";

            try {
                dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
                JSONArray radioArray = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("stations");

                for (int i = 0; i < radioArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject radioObject = radioArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String radioUrl = radioObject.optString("url");
                    String title = radioObject.optString("title");

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, radioUrl);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, title);

                    String radioTitle = "";
                    try {
                        radioTitle = new String(title.getBytes("Cp1252"),"Cp1251");
                        radioTitle = new String(radioTitle.getBytes(),"utf-8");
                        radioTitle = radioTitle.toLowerCase();

                        if (radioTitle.contains(replaceStr)) {
                            radioTitle = radioTitle.replace(replaceStr, "");
                        }

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (isPlay) {
                        if (radioUrl.equals(stream)) {
                            txtTitle.setText(radioTitle.toUpperCase());
                        }
                    } else {
                        txtTitle.setText("");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот класс сервиса

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {
    public static Context context;
    boolean isPlay = false;
    String stream;
    String radio;
    Notification notification;
    Notification status;

    private TelephonyManager tm;
    PlayerService.CallStateListener callStateListener;

    public static final String KEY_STREAM = PlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_STREAM";
    public static final String KEY_RADIO = PlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_RADIO";

    final String myLog = "LOG";

    private void showNotification() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Играет: " + radio)
                .setContentText("Открыть список радиостанций")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "Стоп", pCloseIntent)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
        startForeground(PlayerConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }

    private void showNotificationOld() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Играет: " + radio)
                .setContentText("Открыть список радиостанций")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setDeleteIntent(pCloseIntent)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
        startForeground(PlayerConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        callStateListener = new PlayerService.CallStateListener();
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        context = this;
        this.stream = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_STREAM);
        this.radio = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_RADIO);

        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPlay = true;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                showNotification();
            } else {
                showNotificationOld();
            }
            RadioPlayer.startPlayer(stream, this);

        } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPlay = false;
            RadioPlayer.stopPlayer();
            stopForeground(true);
            Player.btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            Player.isPlay = false;
            stopSelf();
        }

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    if (isPlay == true) {
                        RadioPlayer.stopPlayer();
                        isPlay = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if (isPlay == false) {
                        isPlay = true;
                        RadioPlayer.startPlayer(stream, PlayerService.this);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        RadioPlayer.stopPlayer();
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас или переменная `btnPLayPause` не инициализирована или ресурс `R.drawable.icon_play` не найден. Попробуйте их в консоль вывести и посмотрите где будет NPE.

Comment: Я ведь инициализирую и в коде это видно. Да и ресурс никуда не девается. Данное исключение не всегда выбрасывается. Например на моем устройстве я никогда не получал ошибки, но в маркете у пользователей возникает такая ошибка. Если бы не была инициализация или ресурсе не было, мне кажется исключение выбрасывало бы всегда

Comment: Тогда вы можете попробовать встроить в приложение отправку логов краша приложения например на почту. Может с кодом все в порядке, просто у пользователя кривой телефон.

Comment: мне как-то ответили что нужно переделать логику сервиса, чтобы метод onStartCommand вызывался после всех инициализаций. Но я не пойму как это сделать

Comment: Когда `Activity` не отображается на экране (свёрнута, а тем более закрыта) - она в любой момент может быть выгружена из памяти. И вполне естественно, что в момент, когда юзер нажимает кнопку в уведомлении `Activity` может не существовать. Самое меньшее, что можно сделать - это добавить проверку на `null`.

Comment: где именно добавить проверку?

Comment: При каждом обращении: `if (Player.btnPLayPause != null) Player.btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);`

Comment: А вообще коммуникация между компонентами через статические члены - это не правильный путь. Для этого придуманы бродкасты, интенты, а для сервисов ещё и биндинг.

Comment: А как через броадкасты сделать в моем случае?

Answer (score 2):

В Android весь UI гвоздями прибит к контексту(`Context`) активити/фрагментов. При пересоздании активити пересоздается и его контекст.

Что происходит у вас.

1. `Player` инициализируется, создается его контекст
2. Вы привязываете `btnPLayPause` к некому `View` из этого контекста. (по сути сохраняете в `btnPLayPause` ссылку на объект в контексте)
3. Сворачиваете приложение
4. Андроид принимает решение, что конкретно вот это ваше активити необходимо выгрузить из памяти.
5. Контекст уничтожен
6. Вы из сервиса обращаетесь к `btnPLayPause`, которая указывает в никуда. Здрасте, я ваша NPE!

Собственно поэтому никогда не стоит сохранять в статике что-либо связанное с контекстом (а тем более сам контекст).

Что делать?

1. Забыть про сохранение ссылки на `View` в статическом поле
2. Не пытаться напрямую манипулировать элементами UI из НЕ-UI классов
3. По сути вам нужно просто устанавливать правильный `drawable` при каждом `onResume`, так как менять что-то в свернутой активити смысла мало, ее никто не видит. Ну так и делайте это в самом классе `Player` опираясь на `Player.isPlay`

Comment: Если так. Сделать, то у меня такая проблема. Допустим у нас открыт активити Player. Мы выдвигаем шторку и в уведомлении нажимаем "Стоп". Сервис останавливается, а иконка у кнопки остается такой же, а мне нужно чтобы она поменялась

Comment: @Kolhoznik например с помощью броадкастов. Или же можно организовать подписку на события и дергать из сервиса методы класса оркестратора. Вариантов много

Comment: А можно ссылку на пример, реализованный например через броадкаст?

Comment: @Kolhoznik например вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760338/how-to-receive-an-intent-sent-by-a-service